# Deriving $\int \frac{dz}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\operatorname{Log}(\frac{\tanh(\frac{arcosh(z)}{2})+i}{\tanh(\frac{arcosh(z)}{2})-i})+C$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals

The principal branch is assumed for all mentioned trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions

$\operatorname{Log}$ denotes the principal branch of the natural log defined over the complex numbers
$\DeclareMathOperator{\artanh}{artanh}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arctan}{arctan}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcosh}{arcosh}$

First, we can show that
$$\int \frac{dz}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\int \frac{\sinh\left(\theta\right)d\theta}{\cosh\left(\theta\right)\left(i\sinh\left(\theta\right)\right)}=-i\int\frac{d\theta}{\cosh\left(\theta\right)}=-2i\arctan\left(\tanh\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)+C$$
$$=-2i\arctan(\tanh(\frac{\arcosh(z)}{2}))+C$$
We can also show that

$$\int \frac{du}{1+u^2}=\int \frac{i/2}{u+i}-\frac{i/2}{u-i}du=\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{u+i}{u-i}\right)+C_1=\arctan(u)+C_2$$

And so we obtain

$$\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{u+i}{u-i}\right)=-2i\arctan\left(u\right)+C$$

Substitute
$$u=\tanh\left(\frac{\arcosh\left(z\right)}{2}\right)$$

Then using the above we can finally arrive at
$$\int \frac{dz}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{u+i}{u-i}\right)+C=\operatorname{Log}(\frac{\tanh(\frac{\arcosh(z)}{2})+i}{\tanh(\frac{\arcosh(z)}{2})-i})+C$$

$$=\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{\frac{z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}-1}{z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}+1}+i}{\frac{z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}-1}{z+\sqrt{z^{2}-1}+1}-i}\right)+C$$

Comment: Did you try differentiating your end expression? That might prove illuminating

Comment: yes and it returned the integrand as expected

Comment: It turns out your answer is not correct, see the difference between the two answers [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log%28%28tanh%28arcosh%28x%29%2F2%29%2Bi%29%2F%28tanh%28arcosh%28x%29%2F2%29-i%29%29+-+arsech%28%7Cx%7C%29) and it is not a constant. However, it's just a small error - flipping your logarithm upside down gives that the difference between the answers is $\pi i$. I would not call this an "identity" since as we see here antiderivatives are not unique.

Comment: @NinadMunshi why does Wolfram claim that the derivative of my end expression is the integrand? That would seem to imply that my end expression is indeed an antiderivative of the integrand. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=derivative+ln%5C%2840%29Divide%5Btanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Bi%2Ctanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-i%5D%5C%2841%29

Comment: @NinadMunshi wolfram is saying my answer is correct https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29Divide%5Btanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Bi%2Ctanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-i%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%3DDivide%5B1%2CxSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%5D

Comment: I'm just as confused as you are, I'll have to think about it some more, or someone will come by and help the both of us.

Comment: @NinadMunshi something possibly related to what seems to be going wrong https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770187/confusion-around-ln-frac-tanh-frac-cosh-1x2i-tanh-frac-cosh

Comment: @Ninad, how can you write that the difference is not a constant, and also write that the difference is $\pi i$? Isn't $\pi i$ a constant?

Comment: @GerryMyerson "flipping your logarithm upside down gives that the difference between the answers is $\pi i$"

Comment: OK, @Ninad, all your references to "the two answers" and "the answers" have me confused. Which answers are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Arsech}{Arsech}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Arcosh}{Arcosh}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Arctan}{Arctan}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arsech}{arsech}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\artanh}{artanh}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcosh}{arcosh}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$

I use common conventions for the inverse trigonometric functions, including using lowercase for the conventional principal branches and title case for the corresponding multivalued functions. (The square root $\sqrt{(-)}$ is also taken to be the conventional principal branch.) Then by definition your integral is equal to

$$-\Arsech z +C$$
and your question, in essence, is whether you have correctly demonstrated a relation between $-\Arsech z$ and the inverse tangent, hyperbolic tangent, and inverse hyperbolic cosine. Working with principal branches for the moment, I think your derivation can be usefully interpreted and decomposed into three true claims:

1. If $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, then
   $$-\arsech z = \i(\sgn\Im z)\arcsec z\text{.}$$
   This is an implicit analytic continuation you made that introduced the $\i$ in the hyperbolic substitution.
2. If $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,1]$, then
   $$\arcosh z = 2 \artanh \sqrt{\frac{z-1}{z+1}}\text{.}$$
   This is the hyperbolic substitution that you made.
3. If $z\in \mathbb{C}^{\star}\setminus [-1,1]$, then
   $$\arcsec z = 2 \arctan \sqrt{\frac{z-1}{z+1}}\text{.}$$
   This is the evaluation of the integral in terms of the inverse tangent (as a Weierstrass substitution).

Therefore, it is true that, if $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, then

$$\boxed{-\arsech z = 2\i(\sgn\Im z)\arctan\left(\tanh (\tfrac{1}{2}\arcosh z)\right)}\text{.}$$

The multivalued versions of the inverse functions appearing are
$$\begin{align}
\Arsech z &=\pm\arsech z + 2\pi \i\mathbb{Z} \\
\Arcosh z &=\pm\arcosh z + 2\pi \i\mathbb{Z} \\
\Arctan z &=\arctan z + \pi\mathbb{Z}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Therefore, it is true that, as multivalued functions,
$$\boxed{-\Arsech z = 2\i\Arctan\left(\tanh(\tfrac{1}{2}\Arcosh z)\right)}\text{.}$$

Note, however, that it is *crucial* that both inverse functions appearing on the right-hand side be multiply valued—we lose branches otherwise:
$$\begin{align}2\i\arctan\left(\tanh(\tfrac{1}{2}\Arcosh z)\right)&=\pm\arsech z \\
2\i\Arctan\left(\tanh(\tfrac{1}{2}\arcosh z)\right) &= -\arsech z + 2\pi\i\mathbb{Z}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, use the substitution $x=\operatorname{sech}t$

$$I = \int \frac{-\operatorname{sech}t\tanh t dt}{\operatorname{sech}t\sqrt{1-\operatorname{sech}^2t}} = \int -dt = -t+C$$

Therefore

$$I = -\operatorname{sech}^{-1}|x|$$

for all $x\in(-1,1)$. The relation you have follows from the formula for inverse cosh in terms of log.

Comment: $\cosh^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$ in terms of log is $\ln(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1})$ which means the antiderivative is $\ln(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-{x^2}}+1})$ but I don't see how my relation follows from that. Regardless, what I really want to know is if my derivation of the relation is correct on its own

Comment: @SimonM Use the tanh half angle identity

Comment: since the ln is not unique in complex space, it is not usefull to have a real integral written as a complex ln

Comment: @trula then the useful question is why does Wolfram claim that the derivative of $\ln(\frac{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})+i}{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})-i})+c$ is the integrand in $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I think it's fine to generously assume Wolfram is using "log(x)" the way one would use "Log(z)", the log allowing complex inputs https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=derivative+ln%5C%2840%29+Divide%5Btanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Bi%2Ctanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-i%5D%5C%2841%29

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and then $x^2=1-u^2$ and $du=-\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. So
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int\frac{xdx}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\int \frac{du}{1-u^2}=-\frac12\log\bigg|\frac{1+u}{1-u}\bigg|+C.$$

Comment: So then can I use that to then show that $\frac{-1}{2}\ln\bigg|\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\bigg|=\ln(\frac{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})+i}{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})-i})+c$? All I want is confirmation that $\ln(\frac{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})+i}{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})-i})+c$ is a valid antiderivative of the integrand in question

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\int \frac{1}{x^2} d\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \\
& =-\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}{1-\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}\right|+C \\
O R & =-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: So is my derivation incorrect? All I want to know is whether or not $\ln(\frac{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})+i}{\tanh(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(x)}{2})-i})+c$ is a valid antiderivative of the integrand in question