# On $\displaystyle\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(z)}{2}\right)+i}{\tanh\left(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(z)}{2}\right)-i}+C=-\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-{z^2}}+1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

$\\Log$ denotes the multi-valued natural log defined over the nonzero complex numbers.

Assume $k$ is the particular choice of value of $\cosh^{-1}(z)$ for this post.

I use $=_c$ to denote that if you graph the difference of the two expressions on either side, the graph will be piecewise equal to a number of constants

Why doesn't $$\displaystyle\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(z)}{2}\right)+i}{\tanh\left(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(z)}{2}\right)-i}+C=_c-\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-{z^2}}+1}$$ $\tag1$ imply
$$\\Log\space\left[\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(z)}{2}\right)+i}{\tanh\left(\frac{\cosh^{-1}(z)}{2}\right)-i}+C\right]=_c\\Log\left(-\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-{z^2}}+1}\right)+i(2n\pi){ ?}$$ $\tag2$

This seems to break the rule that if $z=w$ then the set of values you can choose for $\\Log(z)$ are the same set set of values that you can choose for $\\Log(w)$

I know that equation (1) is true. This would seem to imply that equation (2) is true, However, equation (2) is not true. One can show that it is not true by differentiating both sides and seeing that their first derivatives do not match up. Therefore, it cannot be the case that equation (1) being true implies that equation (2) is true.

Why/how doesn't the fact that (1) is true imply that (2) is true?

You can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=derivative%20%20%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29%20Divide%5B-x%2CSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2B1%5D%5C%2841%29-%20%5C%2840%29%20Divide%5Btanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Bi%2Ctanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-i%5D%2Bc%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29) that (1) is true and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=derivative%20%20%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29%20Divide%5B-x%2CSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2B1%5D%5C%2841%29-%20ln%5C%2840%29%20Divide%5Btanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Bi%2Ctanh%5C%2840%29Divide%5Barccosh%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-i%5D%2Bc%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29) that (2) is not true unless $C$ is zero

Comment: I'm guessing I should edit the original to include this as a side question? My apologies, I just thought this was asking a different enough specific question to be different.

Comment: When you state equation (1) you should also make explicit the domain and choice of inverse functions $z\mapsto\cosh^{-1}(z)$.

Comment: What is the role of $C$ in (1)? "There is a constant $C$ for which the two experessions are equal for all $z \in \mathbb C$"? Is that what you are saying...?

Comment: @dfnu yes. I think it's equivalent to saying that the two expressions have the same derivative

Comment: Not exactly. The derivative being zero, the constant may well change over the domain of the original functions. Consider for example $\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ and $\arctan x$. The derivative is $0$, but...

Comment: @dfnu I should state it like this, then. If you graph the difference of the two expressions, the graph will be piecewise equal to a number of constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcosh}{arcosh}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arsech}{arsech}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$
$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$

Work with the conventional principal branches of the square root, logarithm, and inverse trigonometric functions. Recall that if $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,1]$, then
$$\tanh (\tfrac{1}{2}\arcosh z)=\sqrt{\frac{z-1}{z+1}}=\frac{z}{z+1}\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}\text{.}$$

What's true is as follows: if $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, then
$$\boxed{\left(\frac{\i+\tfrac{z}{z+1}\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}}{\i-\tfrac{z}{z+1}\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}}\right)^{\sgn\Im z}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}}\text{;}$$
equivalently,
$$\frac{\i+\tfrac{z}{z+1}\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}}{\i-\tfrac{z}{z+1}\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}}=\frac{1+(\sgn\Im z)\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}\text{.}$$
You can prove this equality with elementary algebra if you use the fact that, when $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$,
$$z\sqrt{1-z^{-2}}=\i(\sgn\Im z)\sqrt{1-z^2}\text{.}$$
Then since the inverse tangent and inverse hyperbolic secant are related to the logarithm by
$$\begin{align}
\arctan z &=\tfrac{1}{2\i}\log \frac{\i + z}{\i - z} & z/\i &\in\mathbb{C}\setminus((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty))\\
\arsech z &= \log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}\right) & z &\in\mathbb{C}\setminus((-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty))\text{,}
\end{align}$$
taking the logarithm of both sides of the boxed equality yields
$$\arsech z = -2\i(\sgn \Im z)\arctan \left(\tanh \tfrac{1}{2}(\arcosh z)\right)\text{.}$$
Note that many of the identities are given on $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, i.e., away from the real axis. Every point *on* the real axis lies on the branch cut of the left- or right-hand sides of these identities—whether with Mathematica or otherwise, you can't reasonably plot the functions involved without understanding the limit interpretation the software is taking at the cut.